# Encountering the issue in running the script!!! Issue: "omegaconf.errors.ConfigAttributeError: Key 'io' is not in struct"

Tags: deep-learning, fb-hydra, omegaconf

By configuring the setup mentioned in (https://github.com/Sachini/niloc), i am facing issue in running the script (test/train). It gives me the following error

```py
  File "/home/omer/anaconda3/envs/niloc_test/lib/python3.8/site-packages/omegaconf/_utils.py", line 610, in _raise
    raise ex  # set end OC_CAUSE=1 for full backtrace
omegaconf.errors.ConfigAttributeError: Key 'io' is not in struct
        full_key: io
        reference_type=Optional[Dict[Union[str, Enum], Any]]
        object_type=dict
```

What are the possible solutions?

I have tried different versions of Omegaconf package but none of them are working

Answer (score 0):

Your config object is missing a field/node `io` which is referenced from the code.
This is a question for the author of the project.

Answer (score -1):

As mentiod above please add `io` in your config file it should resolve this issue.

[image: In this image there is no io so it raise this error]